# Can not select table_name from information_schema.tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my query

```
SELECT  p.table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables p
WHERE table_schema='public' and exists(select *from p.table_name)
```

and it returns

```
EROR : relation "p.table_name" does not exist

SQL state: 42P01 Character: 107
```

Do someone fix this, help me. Thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

This query has not sense. You cannot to use mutable value as column or table name - so fragment `select *from p.table_name` is not legal in SQL.

The sizes of tables (and other info) are stored in `pg_class` table, so you can write query:

```
SELECT relname FROM pg_class c
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
  WHERE relkind = 'r' AND n.nspname = 'public'
   AND reltuples > 0;
```

Or you need dynamic SQL, where mentioned limit doesn't exist.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  r RECORD;
  is_not_empty boolean;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN 
    SELECT table_name 
      FROM information_schema.tables
      WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM public.%I)', r.table_name)
      INTO is_not_empty;
    IF is_not_empty THEN
      RAISE NOTICE '%', r.table_name;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Note: **Use dynamic SQL only when really need it**.

Comment: Oh well, I figure out that everything was wrong. problem solved. Thanks @Pavel Stehule